# Can relative adverb "when" also be used to indicate condition?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, when

As far as I know, I can't use the word "If" to make a relation between noun and clause such as

> *The threshold if X occurs is 40 products at a time.

The right form of it would be

> If X occurs, the threshold is 40 products at a time.

However, is it grammatically correct to do this with the word "when"?
i.e

> The threshold when X occurs is 40 products at a time.

> When X occurs, the threshold is 40 products at a time.

Is the preceding sentence of using when as a relative adverb grammatically correct?

The reason I'm asking it is I'm confused about am I allowed to use the word "when" as a relative pronoun not only for the time but as a condition.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, because the implied meaning is 'on those occasions when...'.

Comment: I appreciate you! @KateBunting

Comment: Not integral to your question, but I'm puzzled by why you dropped the "the" in the examples that start with "threshold"

Comment: I'm also not clear that there's anything wrong with a syntax that inserts the "if clause" between the subject and object, if the clause is set off parenthetically: "The ticket sales, if we have a full house, will cover the costs of the production."

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks for some corrections. For the first comment, I don't know what was wrong with me, and for the second comment, I only thought that the word "if" is not the kind of "relative" family. I'll care more for those that you mentioned!

Comment: 'If X occurs' implies quite strongly that X is known to occur at times. 'If X were to occur / If X occurred' would be purely conditional. / 'When X occurs' implies very strongly that X is known to occur, and/or that it is almost inconceivable that X won't occur in the future.